# ApiExcepction 7 while trying to login with Google Firebase with Kotlin

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

This code worked a couple days ago:

```
private fun googleSignIn() {
        val googleConf = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build()
        val googleClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, googleConf)
        googleClient.signOut()
        getAction.launch(googleClient.signInIntent)
    }
    
    private val getAction =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {
            val data = it.data
            val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
            try {
                val account = task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
                if (account != null) {
                    userViewModel.logInGoogle(account)
                }
            } catch (e: ApiException) {
                snackbar(e.toString())
            }
        }
```

But for some reason now this throws an ApiException with code = 7.
Please help me :(

I tried deleting oath keys in google cloud, and also created a new Firestore project.

Comment: Are you sure that the user is authenticated on the device with a Google account?

Comment: Since you're using Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithGoogle).